# Shortest distance on Repast Simphony?

Tags: geotools, repast-simphony

I wanted to get shortest distance from point a to b on a road network. Is there a way to do that using GeoTools or otherwise? Can we create network projection from road shapefile?

Answer (score 2):

The Repast API has the ShortestPath function (https://repast.github.io/docs/api/repast_simphony/repast/simphony/space/graph/ShortestPath.html) that will provide a list of network edges for the shortest path in a Network.

There is also a model RepastCity (https://github.com/nickmalleson/repastcity) that provide an example of creating road networks and routing.

GeoTools API also provides functionality for graphs and shortest paths: https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/extension/graph/index.html